# Genemu jquery select2 Could not load type "genemu_jqueryselect2_religion"

Tags: jquery, forms, symfony, types

I have a symfony 2.6 project and I've recently installed Genemu jquery select2 from their [form bundle](https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/jquery/select2/index.md), Which says that we need to suffix every type with the name of the form field, But I keep getting this error
 Could not load type "genemu_jqueryselect2_religion" for:

```
->add('religion', 'genemu_jqueryselect2_religion', array(
                    'label' => 'personnel.employee.general_data.form.religion',
                    'placeholder' => '',
                    'class' => 'PersonnelBundle:Lookup\Religion',
                    'property' => 'name',
                    'required' => false
                ))
```

Comment: Use ZenstruckFormBundle instead ;)

Comment: Already did, no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you still getting the same error ?

Don't forget to enable the bundle in AppKernel :

`new Genemu\Bundle\FormBundle\GenemuFormBundle(),`

To configure the bundle in config.yml :

(previous message)

To precise your type in your %entityName%Type.php (this is mine) :

```
  ->add('formation', 'genemu_jqueryselect2_entity', array(
                'class' => 'FormationFrontBundle:Formation',
                'property' => 'name',
                'label' => 'Formation',
                'multiple' => false,
                'placeholder' => 'Sélectionner'
            ))
```

To add JS and CSS from select2 to your form view :

```
{% block scripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% if form is defined %}
        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/adminbundle/js/select2-4.0.0/js/select2.min.js') }}"></script>
        {{ form_javascript(form) }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% if form is defined %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/adminbundle/js/select2-4.0.0/css/select2.min.css') }}">
        {{ form_stylesheet(form) }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: It worked, Thanks very much mate, I wasn't importing the select2 this way, I was using a twig inheritance structure and i was importing the select2 library in the base twig not the form twig .. Now the problem is if I use 'multiple' => true, it generates an error.

Comment: You're welcome ;p
Open a new post for your second issue and print your error

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure the bundle in config.yml ?

Like that :

```
#app/config.config.yml
genemu_form:
    tinymce:
        enabled: true
        theme: modern
        configs:
            entity_encoding: raw
            plugins : 'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview'

    date: ~
    image: ~
    select2:
        enabled: true
        configs:
            placeholder: Select an option
            width: off
            allowClear: false
            minimumInputLength: 0
```

Comment: I found out that this bundle only supports Symfony until 2.3, I am using 2.6, and thank you for answering.

Comment: I've just installed genemu form bundle.

My composer.json :

 `"genemu/form-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",`

And I'm using Symfony 2.6.6 and it works like a charm..

But in my FormType I use : 

`genemu_jqueryselect2_entity` 

Instead of your : `genemu_jqueryselect2_%entityName%`

Comment: Still no luck, I made sure that everything is correctly configured

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this bundle only supports Symfony until 2.3.*